# Problem with calculating the number of examples needed for PAC-learning of conjunction of Boolean literals

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

It was proven that the conjunction of Boolean literals is PAC-learnable and which yielded the inequality

$m ≥(1/\epsilon) ( (\log 3)n + \log(1/\delta))$, as shown below.

However, I plugged in the values $\delta=0.02, \epsilon=0.1$ and $n=10$ yet did not get the value $m\geq 149$, $m$ being the number of examples needed. Could someone tell me why is that and how can I reach the solution of $m\geq 149$ as shown below?

[image]

Comment: I instead got the value of 64.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick calculation with `R` shows

```
> (1/0.1)*(log(3)*10 + log(1/0.02))
[1] 148.9815
```

Thus the bound stated in the paper is correct.

Comment: I used a calculator as well yet got the value of 64.7. Is the base of log in R different? Since I have been using base 10.

Comment: The natural logarithm is the default in `R`; the same I guess can be said for the result of this paper (as it is often the case in mathematical statistics results)

Comment: Unless and otherwise stated, go for natural logarithm as utobi asserted.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will keep that in mind.